# how to change default terminal in ubuntu budgie

Tags: ubuntu, default, terminal-emulator

Ubuntu Budgie comes with tilix by default which may not be suitable for many. When I tried to replace it with xfce4-terminal, I found that nearly most answers included one of the two steps I mentioned below, i.e., editing dconf or updating alternatives. For me neither of them worked when done separately, but when I used them together I was able to change the terminal-emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. sudo apt install xfce4-terminal
2. sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator

Select /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper as your default. there are two modes auto and manual.

3. gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
4. gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"

And now you have xfce4-terminal as your default.

**NOTE:** 
1. Replace "xfce4-terminal" by the one of your choice.

2. If you cannot see your terminal in step 2, use sudo update-alternatives --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>. More about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226919).
3. gsettings is a dconf editor. More about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/334883).